How to hide container processes from the host?
I am running 2 containers in Podman using podman-compose.yml file. When I do a ps -aux or htop on the host machine, the process running inside the container is visible on the host.
How do we hide these processes from the host?
This is podman-compose.yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: app_web:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: app_web
    volumes:
      - ./staticfiles:/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./media:/app/web/media
    networks:
      - app-net
  ngx:
    image: app_ngx:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: app_ngx
    volumes:
      - ./staticfiles:/app/web/staticfiles
      - ./media:/app/web/media
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - app-net
    depends_on:
      - web

networks:
  app-net:
    driver: bridge


You cant. Why should want to do that?

htop lets you add in a cgroup column (see man htop) which you can probably then filter on if you want. I don't know if you can filter OUT specific items though,
